# Rolamento (scroll) do modal não funciona quando dropdown está aberto

Tags: javascript, modal, rolamento, dropdown

Por favor veja em jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/znrktLej/11/

Com dropdown menu aberto, scroll do modal não funciona, fica congelado.

O que estou fazendo de errado ?

Segue código:

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: calc(110vh - 210px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Segue a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na linha vermelha não funciona, enquanto a linha amarela está aberta.

**Navegadores testados:**

Não funciona: Google Chorme e Opera.

Funciona: Firefox, Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer

Comment: Pra mim o scroll funcionou com o dropdown aberto, fechado ou selecionado normalmente @MatheusMiranda. Testei com o Chorme e Firefox.

Comment: @LucasCosta, que estranho porque aqui não funciona com Chorme. Agora com Firefox fucniona.

Comment: Qual versão do chrome?

Comment: @LucasCosta, Versão 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)